# Private sections of text possible in RestructuredText files?

Tags: conditional-statements, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm in the process of converting some of my company's documentation from .md to .rst to be displayed in ReadTheDocs.com

In some of these documents there are Internal sections that are not intended for our customers' consumption.

Is there a way to mark these sections such that Sphinx doesn't render it into HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`ifconfig` directive](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/ext/ifconfig.html).

In your docs:

```
.. ifconfig:: internal

   This stuff is only included in the built docs for internal versions.
```

In your `conf.py`'s `setup` function:

```
def setup(app):
    app.add_config_value('internal', '', 'env')
```