# Hide single section in Sphinx documentation

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, sections

I couldn't find a directive that handles this.

Suppose to have a single `rst` document and for some reason you want to hide a single `section` during the build (no matter if HTML, PDF..), like:

```
Visible section
===============
Here some example I want to show


Not visible section
===================
Some text that I have written but for the current build I want to hide from the final document
```

is there a `.. hidden::` directive that handle this, I'm thinking of something like:

```
Visible section
================
Here some example I want to show

.. hidden::

Not visible section
===================
Some text that I have written but for the current build I want to hide from the final document

.. visible::

Another section
===============
Other visible section in both text and final document
```

Comment: Isn't your question answered there?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49701524/private-sections-of-text-possible-in-restructuredtext-files

Comment: Partially thanks. I found something useful here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313476/how-can-i-configure-sphinx-to-conditionally-exclude-some-pages

Comment: If you start a line with two dots and then a space it does not show up in the documentation. In fact Sphinx automatically creates a section like this and it does not show up:

Answer (score 2):

You can use comment syntax: http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#comments

The version of Sphinx I have got automatically generates an index.rst file that starts with a comment like this:

```
.. sphinx-quickstart on Sat Jun 22 15:48:19 2019.
   You can adapt this file completely to your liking, etc
```

It does not show up in the documentation. You can start lines with two dots and a space followed by your own text and that does not show up either. You need to make sure that all the lines you create are indented the same as the first line. Then the whole section does not show up. Also make sure there is an empty line before the section and after it (unless it is the first section in the file or the last one)

Comment: Comment syntax may be a bit inconvenient for a complete section, because the commented elements must be nested in the comment block. It is fine for shorter parts of if the text editor helps with indenting.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution to hide a section, so it doesn't show up in the HTML ouput.
However, this does not affect the build.

The idea is to use the [class](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/0.7/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#class) diretive and that way be able to assign a CSS class to the section(s). In CSS you can then define the class with `display: none` (or any other CSS).

For you example it would look like (note the identation):

```
Visible section
================
Here some example I want to show

.. class:: hidden

   Not visible section
   ===================
   Some text that I have written but for the current build I want to hide from the final document

Another section
===============
Other visible section in both text and final document
```

In your css you add the following styling:

```
.hidden { display: none }
```

Here is a [link](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/adding-custom-css.html) that explains how to add custom CSS to Sphinx.

Comment: Note: The default domain in Sphinx is the Python domain and it has a `class` directive that shadows the original Docutils directive with the same name. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33497002/407651.